# sqlite in android not recognizing new column I added

Tags: android, sqlite

My db in my app worked fine, then I added odometer to the db.  Now I am getting a table inspections has no column named odometer: , while compiling: INSERT INTO inspections(codriver, odometer, driver, datetime, vehicle_id, status, vehicle_type) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?); error in logcat.  I checked my db adapter and the code is working properly, but for some reason it is not recognizing the new column I added. 
Here is the code from the db

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table inspections ("
            + "_id integer  primary key autoincrement, "
            + "vehicle_id   string  not null, "
            + "vehicle_type string  not null, "
            + "datetime     integer not null, "
            + "driver       string  not null, "
            + "codriver     string  , "
            + "status       integer not null, "
            + "odometer     string  not null "
            + ");";
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

}
```

here is the code for the main db

```
public class SignalSetDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public SignalSetDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Method is called during creation of the database
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    CurrentStateTable.onCreate(db);
    HoursOfServiceTable.onCreate(db);
    InspectionsTable.onCreate(db);
    }

// Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
// e.g. if you increase the database version
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    CurrentStateTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    HoursOfServiceTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
    InspectionsTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
}
```

I can include more code, but pretty sure the error is in the code above

update:
uninstalled the app on the emulator, still getting the same error.  Here is the logcat
03-28 12:52:59.135: D/dalvikvm(331): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 885 objects / 63248 bytes in 78ms
03-28 12:53:05.695: D/dalvikvm(331): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4480 objects / 261760 bytes in 73ms
03-28 12:53:17.065: W/KeyCharacterMap(331): No keyboard for id 0
03-28 12:53:17.065: W/KeyCharacterMap(331): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
03-28 12:53:28.615: I/Database(331): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table inspections has no column named odometer
03-28 12:53:28.715: D/dalvikvm(331): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8584 objects / 420616 bytes in 84ms
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331): Error inserting codriver= odometer=4321 driver=jim datetime=1332964380 vehicle_id=ET 432 status=1 vehicle_type=truck
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table inspections has no column named odometer: , while compiling: INSERT INTO inspections(codriver, odometer, driver, datetime, vehicle_id, status, vehicle_type) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at com.signalsetapp.database.InspectionDBAdapter.insertInspection(InspectionDBAdapter.java:54)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at com.signalsetapp.report.save(report.java:120)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-28 12:53:28.715: E/Database(331):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I would try complete uninstall and install before cracking head on debugging.

Comment: what would I be uninstalling?

Comment: Your app (assuming this is native android app), otherwise I am sorry!

Comment: Did it, still getting the same error

Comment: getting error? could you post stacktrace?

Comment: I think I misunderstood uninstall.  I uninstalled on the emulator and am still getting the same error.  Am I supposed to unistall it elsewhere?

Comment: If you are running on emulator, that should be enough. Post logcat error. As well as try by changing database name to something else.

Comment: rename db to db2 and try? private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db2";

Comment: I remember few days back someone had this issue and had to change database name. Another test is, test on any device.

Comment: Changed the DATABASE_NAME to db2 and version number.  Neither worked. Tried two other emulators and still having the same problem

Comment: Three more tests, 1) change column name to someother column name. 2) Remove the column and check app working fine or not 3) Add column in middle somewhere. If these fails I am sorry! no idea what could it be. One try may be restart machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` is seeing your existing database and so it isn't calling `onCreate`.

You need to uninstall your app so that you get rid of the existing database.

If you're in dev mode, you can just change the `DATABASE_NAME` to db2 as a quick hack to get yourself going, but remember to change it back later once your database is stable.

If you want to do it in the most proper way, you can increment `DATABASE_VERSION`, then implement some `ALTER TABLE` statements in `onUpgrade`.

Comment: I uninstalled my app on the emulator and am still getting the same error.  Is there another place to uninstall it?

Comment: I'd try the db2 hack to get you going for now.  Also, if you look at your emulator's filesystem in ddms (which is nice in Eclipse), you should be able to find the file and its timestamp, probably in a /data/data/com.yourcompany directory.  You can also use the "-" button in Eclipse to manually delete your database file, which actually is a good way to solve your problem now that I think about it.

Comment: where is the "-" button located?

Comment: After I found the "-" button, deleted the old DB, reinstalled the app and it worked

Answer (score 0):

First time when you open the database then  the `onCreate` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` will call and then after it will not call.

And `onUpgrade` method will be call when you upgrade the database version.
So suppose you create your database using the Sqlite version 1.0 then for update the database you will have to change the database version greater than the current version of the database.In your case you will have to **change the `DATABASE_VERSION` variable value to 2.**

**Note:-**
If you change the database version then it will call the `onUpgrade` method so it will execute all the code in this method so you will have to put only those queries for the tables which you want to update else if you put all the tables update queries then it will update all the tables of your database so may be you lost all your previous data from the old database.

Comment: I changed the DATABASE_VERSION and am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to handle this is as follows:

1. Make any changes you want to your table(s)
2. Increment your database version by 1
3. Drop the table(s) completely in `onUpgrade()`
4. Recreate the table(s)/the entire Database within `onUpgrade()` by calling `onCreate()` method.
5. Run your app and the changes to the database or table(s) should be reflected successfully.

Here is the code sample:

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CurrentStateTable_TABLE_CREATE);
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "CurrentStateTable Table created");

            db.execSQL(HoursOfServiceTable_TABLE_CREATE);
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "HoursOfServiceTable Table created");

            db.execSQL(InspectionsTable_TABLE_CREATE);
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "InspectionsTable Table created");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CurrentStateTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + HoursOfServiceTable);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + InspectionsTable);
            onCreate(db);

            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Database successfully upgraded " + "from " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        }
```